# AdminLTE no toma los css

Tags: php, bootstrap

me encuentro con un problema, quiero configurar mi backend con la plantilla adminlte pero no me toma los css, he creado la carpeta vistas dentro de ella he creado un archivo plantilla.php en la cual estoy metiendo el codigo de la plantilla, ademas dentro de esa carpeta he metido los componentes, bower_components, y dist; hago referencia a esas carpetas pero no toma los css, estoy trabajando con el MVC y en mi archivo plantilla_controlador  hago un include hacia la vista, y posteriormente en mi archivo index hago un require hacia el controlador y llamo mi metodo del controlador que me llama la plantilla...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sin codigo o error ni como ayudarte

Comment: tengo las rutas de acorde a la ubicacion de los archivos

Comment: podrías pasar el error que te da en los archivos css

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">

Comment: movi las carpetas bower, dist al directorio principal y tampoco funciona, lo raro es que el archivo, starter.html si me toma los archivos css pero al renombrarlo y ponerle plantilla.php ya no lo toma

Answer (score 0):

utilizo una distro de linux (ELementay OS) el problema era en los permisos solo ejecute estos comandos desde la terminal: find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; y find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; para ello primero debes abrir la ubicacion de tu sitio y luego en la raiz del mismo ejecutar los dos comandos que comparto....si tienen el mismo problema espero te ayude..